# Randomly cycle through widgets using JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've built several widgets and would like populate a different widget whenever the webpage is refreshed. I'm still fairly new writing JavaScript and I can't seem to get the code to work.

**Please see the HTML and JavaScript code below**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Array of files to load via AJAX
  var files = [
    'wedding.html',
    'wellness.html',
    'sports.html'
  ];
  var url = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];
  $.get(url, function (data) {
    $('#c5Atrium').html(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>C5 Widget</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Start code for c5 widget -->
    <div id="c5widget"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sever-path.com/c5_widget.js"></script>
    <!-- End code for c5 widget -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What **IS** Random? https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png --   All jokes aside .. What exactly is the issue you are having?  I don't see a *question* denoting the issue you're having with your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DIV in html is called "c5widget" but you you are trying to access it by id "#c5Atrium"

Change

```
$('#c5Atrium').html(data);
```

to

```
$('#c5widget').html(data);
```

or maybe "c5widget" is used for something else and you are missing the div with id "c5Atrium". In that case add a div with id "c5Atrium"

```
<div id="c5Atrium"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Nawed. That was an additional issue that I overlooked. I'm trying to figure whats causing the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" in the browser. I'm showing '$' is not defined. (no-undef) in my editor.

Comment: I've updated the code using vanilla JavaScript. I can get the array to cycle through but the filename is display as a string rather than the actual widget.  

**Updated Code**
                                                  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

var files = ['family.html', 'weddings.html', 'sports.html'];
var url = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];

document.getElementById('c5widget').innerHTML = url;

});

Comment: you replaced ajax call to simple document.getElementById('c5widget').innerHTML = url; that is exactly the code is doing.. "put the url in the div".

Comment: No luck on getting the actual widget to populate. I'm looking into AJAX calls for Vanilla JavaScript. I see the "responseText" returns results as a string. Do you know if there is a equivalent request to display the actual widget within a webpage?

Comment: what is a "widget"? You are technically trying to load the html as a string in the div. But if you have javascript and html/body/head/script tags then of course it will not execute. Look into iFrame for that where you show a whole web page in a frame.

Comment: The "widget" is similar to an ad that will display in the sidebar of the webpage. I've switched back to the jQuery code which is now working correctly on my localhost server, but I'm getting the error '$' is not defined.  This is the code:

$(document).ready(function () {
  // Array of files to load via AJAX
  var files = [
    'weddings.html',
    'family.html',
    'sports.html'
  ];
  var url = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];
  $.get(url, function (data) {
    $('#c5widget').html(data);
});
});

Comment: '$' is not defined usually means you do not have JQuery attached.